# ArcGIS Pro not opening .tif image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

I have problem with opening big .tif image(121gb) with ArcGIS Pro. Whereas it opens in QGIS without any problems.

ArcGIS Pro:
[image]

QGIS:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you built pyramids for the data in QGIS but not yet in ArcGIS Pro?  The pyramid files would be different so the QGIS pyramids would not apply to ArGIS Pro.   https://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/pyramid-layers-qgis-arcgis

Comment: In my experience, pyramid format for tiffs are the same for QGIS and ArcGIS (both use GDAL internally to read tiff), and the article you linked states the same - "*If you ever wondered if the pyramid file (.ovr) was viewable in both ArcGIS and QGIS – it is. Build it once and either can read it.*"

Comment: Have you tried Zoom To Layer to see whether your image is just not within the current extent?

Comment: Scales in the screen captures feels wrong, 1 to 100 millions.

Comment: There can be many reasons. But first thing to try is right click in your contents pane and click "Zoom to layer". If nothing is shown, then check projection of a layer in properties if the right one is assigned.

Comment: If i use Zoom To Layer  in QGIS image dissapears. In ArcGIS Zoom To Layer does nothing